# Mongoose query for getting child and grand-child in a collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

**What I have:**

I have a collection in mongo which has many documents. The collection is called `Users`. For sample purposes I have shown 7 records of all.

```
{
    _id: _______________________,
    name: Mary    
},
{
    _id: _______________________,
    name: John,
    manager: objectId("id of Mary");
},
{
    _id: _______________________,
    name: Tim,
    manager: objectId("id of John");
},
{
    _id: _______________________,
    name: Tom,
    manager: objectId("id of John");
},
{
    _id: _______________________,
    name: Henry,
    manager: objectId("id of Tim");
},
{
    _id: _______________________,
    name: Mark,
    manager: objectId("id of Henry");
},
{
    _id: _______________________,
    name: Todd,
    manager: objectId("id of Mary");
}
```

By taking a look at the above data, you can see a relationship as follows:

```
                                 Mary
                                   |
                  -------------------------------------
                  |                                   |
                John                                Todd
                  |
      --------------------------
      |                         |
     Tim                       Tom
      |
    Henry
      |
    Mark
```

**What I want:**

I want a mongoose query, which returns me all the records with its child and grand-child. So, for example, if I want to have all the users under John including John, then my output should look something like:

```
{
    _id: _______________________,
    name: John,
    manager: objectId("id of Mary");
},
{
    _id: _______________________,
    name: Tim,
    manager: objectId("id of John");
},
{
    _id: _______________________,
    name: Tom,
    manager: objectId("id of John");
},
{
    _id: _______________________,
    name: Henry,
    manager: objectId("id of Tim");
},
{
    _id: _______________________,
    name: Mark,
    manager: objectId("id of Henry");
}
```

**What I don't want:**

I know that data is relational, so some people may advice me that I should use a relational database. But right now I am trying to learn mongodb and Node.js. So, I would like to stick with mongodb.

I also know that it is possible to have a collection which holds all the data like this:

```
var ManagerSchema = new Schema({
   manager_name: String,
   users: [users]
}

var UserSchema = new Schema({
   user_name: String
})
```

But I don't want above mentioned stuff.

I just want to have only one collection and the data will be relational.

Comment: take a look at the [**graphLookup**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/) operator introduced in mongodb 3.4

Comment: I haven't used the graphLookup yet, that might be the best solution for this. Otherwise I think the only way you can do this is to do it in separate queries - which I can help with if you like.

Comment: @felix I have taken a look at graph Lookup in the documentation. As far as I think, graph Lookup returns heirarchical data. But I want flat data as mentioned in question.

Comment: @Aron I would like to take a look at your answer.

Comment: @Vishal does my answer help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to do it in 3 stages:

1. First get John by querying by his `_id`
2. Get John's 'children' by searching for users who have John's id as their manager
3. Get John's 'grandchildren' by querying for all users who have *any* of John's children as their manager. The MongoDB `$in` operator is useful here

The code:

```
const idOfjohn = '1234567890abcdef';
let john, children, grandchildren; // initialise variables

Users.findById(idOfjohn) // find John
    .then(user => {
        john = user; // assign to variable with wider scope

        return Users.find({ manager: idOfjohn }); // find users whose manager is John
    })
    .then(users => {
        children = users;
        const childrenIDs = users.map(user => user._id); // make array of IDs

        return Users.find({ manager: { $in: childrenIDs } }); // find users whose managers have John as a manager
    })
    .then(users => {
        grandchildren = users;

        const all = [john]
            .concat(children)
            .concat(grandchildren); // create a single array

        console.log(all); // or do whatever
    });
```

**EDIT**

OP clarified that he needs it for n levels of descendants.

You can do this with the [`co`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/co) library's [`wrap`](https://github.com/tj/co#var-fn--cowrapfn) function, like so:

```
const { wrap } = require('co');


const findWithDescendants = wrap(function*(topUserId, generations) {
    const topUser = yield Users.findById(topUserId); // get John himself

    let users = [topUser]; // will hold all users
    let ids = [topUserId]; // will hold IDs to search in

    for (let i = 0; i < generations; i++) {
        const thisLevelUsers = yield Users.find({ manager: { $in: ids } });

        ids = thisLevelUsers.map(user => user._id); // replace with new IDs
        users = users.concat(thisLevelUsers); // add new users
    }

    return users;
});

findWithDescendants(idOfjohn, 3)
    .then(users => {
        console.log(users); // or do whatever
    });
```

Note: to ensure there are no duplicates you could either use something like a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) instead of an array for `users`, *or* you could add each user into `users` one by one, checking for each one that they are not already present in the `users` array.

Comment: I want it to be applicable for nth child. So i don't think i will be using code given by you. Thanks for any help.

Comment: I updated to my answer to retrieve descendants n levels deep.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I will check it and tell you if any changes are necessary/

Comment: If I console.log(topUser) inside findWithDescendants function after const topUser = ......, then I get all direct children of John. But just before return users statement, if I console.log(users); then I don't get any user logged. There are no errors in console. I don't know why its doing like this.

Comment: Sorry I can't help you with debugging. If you have a specific error or if there's a bug in the code I will try and solve it but I don't know what's happening on your machine.

Comment: It's possible that one of the mongoose `find` functions is throwing an error. Best way to solve that is to add `try catch` blocks around each of them, so that you can log any errors in the `catch` block.

Comment: Got it!!! There was a typo. But now there is a bug in code. I get results repeated so many times in different arrays. Can you take a look at the code again?

Comment: I'm pleased you got it working. As I said in my answer, my code does mean there may be duplicates. You can prevent having duplicates in `users` by one of the two methods I stated in my note at the bottom of my answer. I'm confident you can implement this yourself :)

Comment: Meanwhile if my answer helped, please mark it as accepted (and I wouldn't say no to an upvote either)

Comment: Ok I will try to implement it myself. But why I get two arrays? I mean the pattern of output is : `[[{Tim object}, {Tom object}], {Tim object}, {Tom object}, {Henry object}]`. I haven't inserted `Mark` record yet. One more thing. John's record is not present in the output.

Comment: My bad. Had a bug. Just fixed it.

Comment: Thanks. I right now taken a look at your updated code. But I have already solved my problem using your answer. Thanks again.